# CSV to JSON using file upload

Tags: node.js, npm, multer

I want to covert CSV file to JSON Array object using file upload.

i have tried multer,

```
module.exports = function(express, app, upload){
    var router = express.Router();
    var util = require('util');

    router.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.send(200);
    });
    router.post('/csv', upload,function(req,res){
        //How to get file contents ?
        res.send('/dashboard');
    });
    app.use('/upload',router);
};
```

where upload is,

```
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('csvfile');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to extract a body from the request. `bodyparser` https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser is a fine tool for doing this.

First, install and require the library. Then, create a `text` bodyparser (probably the best fit for `csv` use-case) and register it as a middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()) // app being 'var app = express()' server
```

finally:

```
router.post('/csv', upload,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body) // req.body should be populated by request body
    res.send('/dashboard');
});
```

Note however, that `bodyparser` is not suited for multipart bodies. If this is your case, use something as https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

Answer (score 4):

Jay.

If you have small csv files you can use memory for multer.

```
var upload = multer({ inMemory: true}).single('csvfile');
```

And after this you must transform csv

```
router.post('/csv', upload, function(req,res){
     var csvString = req.files.csvfile.buffer.toString()
     converter.fromString(csvString, function(err,result){
         if(err)return res.send("ERR")
         res.send(result);
     }); 
});
```